# I'm using react for making a Spotify clone and I'm getting an error for user authentication that INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI

Tags: spotify

I'm getting a error I'm using React.js

```
export const authEndpoint = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize";

const redirectUri = "http:/localhost:3000/";
const clientId ="XXXXXXXX";

const scopes = [
    "user-read-currently-playing",
    "user-read-recently-played",
    "user-read-playback-state",
    "user-top-read",
    "user-modify-playback-state",


];

export const loginUrl = `${authEndpoint}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scopes.join("%20")}&response_type=token&show_dialog=true`;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to specify what errors you're getting and explain what you're trying to do and what is your expected result.

Comment: user authentication is not a function of react js but that of the APIs that you are using or the method that is being used to call the APIs. Please share how are you invoking your APIs and probably the authentication code.

Answer (score 0):

try look at the register url on Spotify dashbord, you have to set the same url on your aplication